# sanitize_post() is not sanitizing Post Object

Tags: wp-query, security, array

I wanted to sanitize a WP_Query post object without using foreach.

I used this method:

```
$args = array(
// ...
)
$data = array();

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

$data["post"] = $the_query->posts;

array_map("sanitize_post", $data["post"]);

return rest_ensure_response($data);
```

output:

[image]

as you can see that filter is working and its turning to "Display" from "Raw".

But the problem is: `<script>` tags still standing in post_title field.

Whats the problem?

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs that suggests that `sanitize_post` is supposed to remove script tags.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Then why we have this function? Main reason behind sanitizing is XSS in my opinion.

Comment: I guess I figured it out. I'm editing my question.

Comment: _Escaping_ is for preventing XSS.

Comment: You are right, I'm already escaping every data that comes from input. Preparing and saving to DB. I'm not saving to DB a script tag free data. But I wanted to try WordPress's default "add post" thing and entered a script alert code and it worked. I know website owner will not try to add a XSS code in his title but it's always the best sanitizing data before print it to the screen IMO. Added an answer to below ^_^

Comment: That is not what `sanitize_post` does, and ***you shouldn't be using it to sanitize REST API responses***, nor should you be returning the posts array directly. Is there a reason you aren't using the standard REST API endpoint?

Comment: @TomJNowell thank you for your answer! So you are saying I need to use foreach and sanitize every needed fields by one by right? Like: for thumbnail esc_url, for post_title sanitize_text_field etc. ? I'm working on a big database, and for my PHP version (8.0) array_map performs a little bit faster than foreach. If it's not a good practice ofc I will need to use foreach.

Comment: I'm saying that you need to provide more context because this is one of those situations where it is not possible to solve the question and secure the code without knowing what the purpose is and why you did this

Comment: Also keep in mind that a script tag being in the title is only possible if you're using the insecure `unfiltered_html` capability which is added to the super admin/administrator role ( I recommend removing it ), and that even if it did get into the post title, and it did get sent back to the client, effective security on the client side should prevent it from being inserted, and if that failed, prevent it from executing. Without knowing the purpose of the REST endpoint however, it's not possible to say what you should do. _Context is incredibly important, especially with security_

Comment: I'm building a social media theme with wordpress that uses rest api mostly. There are a lot of user inputs that send data to the server. I'm sanitizing them all, using prepare in all of my queries with intvals and etc. and then saving to the DB. In this code I'm getting posts by some filters and sending them to the client side with rest api to show it on front end and working on it with vanilla js then innerHTML'ng to where it belongs. All I wanna is sanitize post's title and other fields that I need to work on. -----

Comment: ---- my front end post submission forms already sanitizes the data that came from user and saves it. I don't save a data that contains tags in it. I just tried to add a post from wp-admin with "add post" button and titled it like its a XSS code. And It worked. I did'nt wanted that and wanted delete every tags in my rest response. Thats all.

Comment: So you're using a `thread` CPT rather than comments. In that case, you should have specified `show_in_rest` as true and let WP core do all the sanitising and escaping. Escaping not sanitisation is what you should have done. Sanitising doesn't secure data, it _cleans_ data. Cleaned up data can still be dangerous. Escaping is what makes data safe. The reason adding dangerous tags worked is because you did it as an admin user with the `unfiltered_html` capability, which lets you bypass security normally applied

Comment: Developers with far more experience and skill than both of us combined built the official endpoints, and wrote APIs to validate and sanitize responses ( you should be using the validation and sanitising API arguments when registering an endpoint to do all of this, including authentication, you're not supposed to do this in the endpoint itself )

Comment: If I tries to add a XSS code from my front end post submission form my function already uses sanitize_text_field, intval and preapre commands. I'm not saving a data that insecure. This is a situation I only faced when I add a post to the wordpress in wp-admin with admin role.

Comment: As I said, your administrator has the `unfiltered_html` capability, so all security was bypassed. Remove that capability and the problem goes away.

Comment: You're meant to use the sanitisation argument for sanitising: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#sanitizing, and you should use the official REST API endpoint that `show_in_rest` adds, and use `pre_get_posts` to make any adjustments to what it displays to the user.

Comment: You are right but I could'nt understand that part of :"you should be using the validation and sanitising API arguments when registering an endpoint to do all of this" I have only 1 variable in this rest api endpoint and I'm using 'sanitize_callback' => 'absint' on it when registering my custom endpoint. When an user sends a data to my rest api (which one saves data to database, this one only GET the data) I'm already using sanitize_callback for them. If I'm making it via admin-ajax.php I'm using prepare on my quaries and using intval on int variables or sanitize_text_field on texts. ---

Comment: Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

sanitize_post is coming with "display" default filter option. And it does not sanitize tags.

But if you tries a code like this:

```
 $sanitizer = function($post){
 return sanitize_post($post, "db"); // or "edit"
};

array_map($sanitizer, $data["post"]);
```

Now it sanitizes fields against XSS!

[image]